# XNA library references

Tags: c#, xna

I have one problem with XNA or Visual Studio.

I have Windows 8.1 64, VS 2013 Ultimate
Below i put 2 imigaes that describe it perfectly.

All is ok, reference is added, using too cant see my class.
Even is if I write Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime it will highlight "GameTime"
(http://i62.tinypic.com/2eq8468.png)
Same solutiion, different project all llike before (besides it is XNA-type of project) but now it is working
(http://i60.tinypic.com/5fqeyx.png)
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an earlier version of VS. I've had weird problems with XNA on VS13. Switched to VS10 and problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to add Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game as well.